# how show only limited content in table view?

Tags: iphone, view, uitableview, nsarray

I am new for iPhone development. I don't have any idea that How show array in Table view? Now problem is that i am coding to display an array of 85 strength. Now i want to show in slots in table view. for example when first time view did load then table show 10 element and in 11th row show a button Next. When click on Next then show next 15th element and in 16 th row show two button.One is next and second is previous. When click on next then show next 15 element and when click on previous then show previous 10 element. How do and where do in coding part?
I am get data in array from XML parsing. That array i have shown i view did load.In number of row i have written [tmparray count]+1. Tmparray have first ten element.

What i will do next? Thanks in advances..................

Comment: This differ from previous question?

Comment: please post some code for exact query.... and this is same as your previous question which i have answered....

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an array method that returns your content array filtered with [NSArray filteredArrayWithPredicate:].